# Connection to local MySQL server succeeds with wrong connection details?

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, mysql-connector

I use MySQL within my application and I just tried to connect to my local MySQL server.
First I tried to connect using the right connection details (localhost, user: root, no password). It succeeds.
Then I tried to connect using the wrong connection details (localhost, user: root1, password: 123). It failed.
But if i leave the password blank then it succeeds? I dont know why but everytime i leave the password blank and only provide a username (whatever username you can imagine) it succeeds!
Can anyone help me with this crazy error? Dont know why the server doesn't reject my connection attempt.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: MySQL by default is installed with user ="root" and password is blank. If you want to have some password, then you need to set it manually

Comment: Yes i know it but what about changing the username to something else than "root" when connecting? It should fail but it doesn't.

Comment: Are you sure it is really connecting? Are you able to execute any query, or perform other task normally, with username other than "root"?

Comment: No i cannot execute queries without getting any error but i wonder why there is no error while connecting. if i provide a password then an error is thrown but if i leave it then there isn't any error.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to changed the root password to something it hasn't been before. Then, FLUSH PRIVILEGES. Problem solved. You won't be able to log in locally with a blank password (same through PhpMyAdmin).

For more details, you can visit this link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/default-privileges.html